# Is it possible to create UITextRange manually for first character?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextrange

Is it possible to instantiate `UITextRange` and for first character of `UITextField`?
i need to access to rect of `UITextField` 's first character, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can manually create a `UITextRange` with the methods provided by `UITextInput`:

```
UITextPosition *firstCharacterPosition = [textField beginningOfDocument];
UITextPosition *secondCharacterPosition = [textField positionFromPosition:firstCharacterPosition offset:1];
UITextRange *firstCharacterRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:firstCharacterPosition toPosition:secondCharacterPosition];
NSString *firstCharacter = [textField textInRange:firstCharacterRange];
```

Comment: when i use this code in `resignFirstResponder` overrided in subclass of `UITextField` , `firstCharacter` almost is null. where i use from this code for working properly?

Comment: This code worked inside an editing changed event (`[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidEdit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged]`). Maybe the text field has to be first responder?